# Bootstrap 3 Container Fill Left and Right space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently trying to create a centered container using bootstraps container class, and then to the left and right of it have two separate divs that fill the remainder of the white space.

I tried alot things, busy trying to create it using columns now. But no Luck.

Only thing is, the container needs to have a max width of 960px

here's a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/yW6hJ/)**

and the code thus far:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-1 pull-left" style="background: #000099;">left</div>
    <div class="container" style="background: #002500">contain</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 pull-right" style="background: #005580">right</div>
</div>
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: you need a width of `960px`? why not have a look at the `960` css framwork? http://960.gs/

Comment: unfortunately already built 90% of it using bootstrap. this is just about the last issue. Will look into it though thanks.

Comment: You need a 960px width or a max width of 960px? ..meaning that it's ok also 945px for example?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Bootstrap grid has 12 colums, it would look more like this..

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background: #000099;">left</div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="background: #002500">contain</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background: #005580">right</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/129827

**EDIT** - For a 960px width container, you could add a special class ie; `container-960` like this..

```
.container-960 {
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

I updated the demo: http://bootply.com/129827

Comment: And if the container has to have a max-width of 960?

Comment: left and right need to fill the remainder of the space though?

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven How do you mean? As in not having the left & right columns at all? Or the middle container to be 960px width with two 40px columns at either side? (To a total of 1040px for all columns?). This answer is pretty worth of a **+1** as it is without more requirement changes.

Comment: Oh, so you want to mix fixed and fluid?

Comment: what i mean is there should be a 960 container centered in the page and then the remainder of the white space left and right need to be two separate divs. please let me know if what im saying is unclear, then ill try and explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to fill the left and right of the container with a color (and not content), then you can use a colored border and some CSS3 calculations:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    border-left: calc(50vw - 375px) solid red;
    border-right: calc(50vw - 375px) solid green;
    /* this was width: 750px; */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    border-left: calc(50vw - 485px) solid red;
    border-right: calc(50vw - 485px) solid green;
    /* this was width: 970px; */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    border-left: calc(50vw - 585px) solid red;
    border-right: calc(50vw - 585px) solid green;
    /* this was width: 1170px; */
  }
}
```

These rules won't work on IE8 and lower and older versions of Chrome have a bug that prevent this from working. If you are okee with that, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Override the container-fluid.

```
.container-fluid{
   padding-left:0;
   padding-right:0;
}
```